# What is the highest temp. to age a Russian imperial stout?

Tags: aging

I'm planning on brewing a RIS maybe the next month and I was thinking of leave it in the secondary for a couple of weeks and then pass it to a keg and leave it at room temp for a few months.  The thing is that my average room temp is around mid/high 80s F (say 84-88).

Is this an acceptable temp for aging a RIS?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question, especially the comments about Charlie Bamforth's research. http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/how-much-does-heat-affect-beer

Comment: The quote is partially correct: every 10 deg. C increase, increases the rate of staling by 2-3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a beer that tastes on the aged side, then maybe it would be ok. The bigger beers tend to fare better with higher temperatures - the darker malts act as anti-oxidants.

I have a RIS that has been standing at around 70°F/21°C for 6 months. It's definitely changed without question - not as fresh as it was, but also still a pleasant beer since the flavors blend together better now, but one keg has definitely picked up a hint of sherry.

While the RIS will stand up to more "abuse" at higher temperatures, there is a limit, and 3-4 months at 84-88F is probably pushing it - it's the equivalent of ca. a year's aging at 70F, or 3 years at 50F.

If you have any alternative, cooler storage, I would go for that. Otherwise look for ways to reduce the time at that higher temp to the minimum.

Comment: Why will an RIS stand up to more abuse?

Comment: "The bigger beers tend to fare better with higher temperatures - the darker malts act as anti-oxidants."

Answer (score 2):

That's way too high a temp for good results.  You could keep it there for a short period without suffering terrible results, but the higher the temp the faster the beer will stale.  I wouldn't leave it at that temp for more than a week.